# Determining mathematical expression for Boolean logic with 5 raster layers in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, raster-calculator, boolean

I have 5 layers in ArcGIS 10.2 for Desktop, and i want to apply Boolean Logic. What will be the mathematical expression in "Raster Calculator".

I know that for to layers expression will be like ("layer1"==1)&("layer2"==1)
I am trying following expression for 5 layers all together ... but I am getting an error message.

[image]

Comment: You are missing an obvious bit of information, what is the error message?